# Trying to print out numberOfCameras() on screen

Tags: java, android

I am currently learning Java and a bit of Android programming and I just wanted to play a bit with the Camera on my phone. So first I want to print out the number of Cameras on the screen using the *getNumberOfCameras()* method.

So here is the relevant part of my source code:

```
TextView AnzahlKameras = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValAnzahlKamerasTextView);

int numberOfCameras;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam_stream);
    numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    AnzahlKameras.setText(numberOfCameras);
}
```

As you see, I have created a TextView in which I want to print out the number of cameras. The way I understand it, *getNumberOfCameras()* just prints out an integer. I just modified the code of the autogenerated "main" class.

The code seems fine and I can export a **.apk* file and install it on my phone. However, whenever I try to start the app it gives an error saying that the app had stopped working and it throws me back to my home screen.

I would be grateful for any kind of help and forgive me if this seems to be a stupid question. Consider me a newbie to all of this.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the requested logfile.

```
01-07 11:29:06.665 I/ActivityManager(2544): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:de.phkr.camstream time:11468943
01-07 11:29:06.665 I/ActivityManager(2139): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=de.phkr.camstream/.CamStream} from pid 2544
01-07 11:29:06.866 I/ActivityManager(2139): Start proc de.phkr.camstream for activity de.phkr.camstream/.CamStream: pid=22295 uid=10115 gids={50115, 1006, 1028, 1015}
01-07 11:29:07.066 E/AndroidRuntime(22295): Process: de.phkr.camstream, PID: 22295
01-07 11:29:07.066 E/AndroidRuntime(22295): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.phkr.camstream/de.phkr.camstream.CamStream}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 11:29:07.066 E/AndroidRuntime(22295):     at de.phkr.camstream.CamStream.<init>(CamStream.java:11)
01-07 11:29:07.076 W/ActivityManager(2139):   Force finishing activity de.phkr.camstream/.CamStream
01-07 11:29:07.826 W/ActivityManager(2139): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{425392e8 u0 de.phkr.camstream/.CamStream t14 f}
01-07 11:29:08.928 I/ActivityManager(2139): Process de.phkr.camstream (pid 22295) has died.
```

Comment: Have you register this activity on `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: please see my answer. It will solve your problem I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
If you have already added permission then there is a silly mistake, i.e.,

replace `AnzahlKameras.setText(numberOfCameras);` by `AnzahlKameras.setText(" "+numberOfCameras);`

Also call `TextView AnzahlKameras = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValAnzahlKamerasTextView);` this inside onCreate() method

I think it will be solved.

Comment: Yes I know that, main problem was AnzahlKameras.setText(numberOfCameras); if numberOfCameras will be a String then it will run, but though it's integer, so for this reason need a string first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add theses permissions to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Try this :

```
TextView anzahlKameras;

int numberOfCameras;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam_stream);
    numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    anzahlKameras= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ValAnzahlKamerasTextView);
    anzahlKameras.setText(numberOfCameras);
    }
```

You have to use findViewById  during or after the `OnCreate` method. Otherwise, it will return `null`

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I already added the permissions to my Manifest and they are being shown on my Andoid device under "Apps -> NameOfMyApp".

Comment: Also do not forget that every field/variable in java must start with a lowercase caracter. Its convention

Comment: Thanks! This and the answer posted by Satyaki Mukherjee solved it.